# Chromium profile "could not be opened correctly" errors

Tags: 10.10, chromium

For some reason I've recently been getting a profile error on chromium:

[image]

I can't seem to see what the problem is, is it associated with the fact that chromium thinks it hasn't been shut down properly (and even then, I can't see how else I'm supposed to shut it down, other than clicking the close button). The result is that I cannot access any of my history, bookmarks etc, something of an annoyance.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a thorough guide on a blog as to the steps you could take to [troubleshoot this problem](http://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/how-to-solve-your-profile-could-not-be-opened-correctly-issue-in-chrome-or-chromium-without-losing-your-profile/).

Answer (score 2):

You could backup your `/home/user/.config/chromium` folder and launch Chromium. In the new autocreated folder copy the desired content of Default folder in the backup, such as Bookmarks, History, and so on.

Comment: This should be `~/.config/chromium`

Comment: Oh, yes. My fault. Edited.

Comment: and doing this: `chmod -R ~/.config/chromium && chmod -R ~/.cache/chromium`.  I couldn't believe how many people didn't realize that it wasn't chromium issue but Ubuntu itself with its own setup of user and group.

Answer (score 1):

Stop cromium

```
cd /home/user/.config/chromium
mv Default Backup
```

start chromium

stop chromium

```
sudo cp -rapf Backup/* Default
```

I don't know why this works because it seems you are just moving the broken crap back into the folder but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem defenitively with this script :

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# Execute this script as root after you have installed chromium-browser package.
# This script create a new patched launcher without any modification of the original files.
#
# To remove the patched launcher created with this script :
#
# sudo rm /usr/bin/chromium-browser-patched
# sudo rm /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser-patched.desktop
#

cat > /usr/bin/chromium-browser-patched <<PATCHEND
#!/bin/bash

#
# This is a chromium-browser patched launcher script to fix the common profile connection error.
#
# By Luc Bruninx 2014-09-16 on Ubuntu 14.04
#

if [[ -d "\$HOME/.config/chromium.bak" ]]; then
  rm -fr "\$HOME/.config/chromium.bak"
fi

if [[ -d "\$HOME/.config/chromium" ]]; then
  mv "\$HOME/.config/chromium" "\$HOME/.config/chromium.bak"
  cp -r "\$HOME/.config/chromium.bak" "\$HOME/.config/chromium"
fi

\$(dirname \$0)/chromium-browser

PATCHEND

chmod a=r+w+x /usr/bin/chromium-browser-patched

cat /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop | sed "s/Exec=chromium-browser/Exec=chromium-browser-patched/g" | sed "s/Chromium-browser/XXXREPLACE01XXX/g" | sed "s/Chromium/Patched\ Chromium/g" | sed > /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser-patched.desktop "s/XXXREPLACE01XXX/Chromium-browser/g"
```

Execute this script as root once you have installed chromium-browser package. It create a new patched launcher icon without any modification of the original files of the chromium official package from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Was enough to remove `rm -rf Web\ Data` from `~/.config/chromium/Default`.

- had to restart computer.